# Why are my sprite sheet's frames not visible in Cocos Builder?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-sheet, cocosbuilder, zwoptex

I have created a sprite sheet with zwoptex. Then I just dragged the *.plist* and *.png* files to my Cocos Builder project. After this I wanted to take a sprite frame and set it to a sprite:

[image]

But the sprite image is empty !! Af first I thought it was just empty in Cocos Builder, and that it must have been working correctly when imported to a project. But if I try to run that scene with *CCBReader* I still see an empty sprite. Why?

Comment: Am I including too few details? Did someone try the same thing and succeeded it? Some feedback would be useful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the plist format was invalid, I created it with zwoptex and then I renamed it, so the plist didn't contain the true file name. I recreated it from scratch with zwoptex and now the sprite frames are being recognized from Cocos Builder.